# Can't resolve hostnames over LAN

Tags: networking, hostname

Occasionally our LAN stops resolving host names. We have no idea why this happens. How can we diagnose these issues?

We have two routers. One is connected to the internet (via a fiber modem). The other one is set up as a wireless switch. i.e. it serves the internet via the first router, but it is in a different room and is used for Ethernet connections to computers in that room.

The issue seems to stem from the first router (or something else). I doubt its the switch router, or any issue with config across the network. This is because we usually type `http://home` to get to the router config for the internet connected router, but this isn't working.  However, we can type in the IP address and get to the config page. This happens whether we are connected to the original or the switch router.

Similarly we have a web server on the lan which we normally use the hostname of the computer to access, which we cannot do over the network (again the ip address works though).

Similarly pinging the IP addresses on the network works, but host names don't.

I am not aware how we fix this, if at all. We normally restart the routers and such and they come back. This time they haven't though, so I am looking for a little more insight as to why this may be happening.

Comment: what is the model of the two routers?

Comment: Is this a Windows or Linux environment?  Are you using an internal DNS server?

Comment: The first router is a 2wire bt home hub router, the second is a netgear router. I appologise, I am now away from work and cannot find model numbers. The server is linux, plus is running a windows 7 vm which won't resolve either. We also have a netgear NAS box, various windows computers and various Mac computers connecting to the network. None will resolve and none can resolve other host names... :/ Thanks guys.

Comment: Where is name resolution supposed to happen?  On the linux server?

Comment: Nope... over the router I guess. It has its own DNS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information you provided, you should start by determining whether the router's DNS service is actually working or not. You should be able to determine this by looking at the configuration for the router to see if the service is up or not, but if there are no indicators to help you, you can resort to a port-scan.

---

### SKIP THIS SECTION IF YOUR ROUTER TOLD YOU DNS IS LIVE:

Use a tool such as [nmap](https://nmap.org/). You can download it quickly for your Linux server, since it is included in most default package repositories for your standard Linux distros (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, Mint, Fedora, Redhat, etc). Depending on whether you are running a Debian-based or RPM-based distribution, your command syntax may differ.

- For Debian:

  - To Search for `nmap`: `sudo apt-cache search nmap`
  - To Install `nmap`: `sudo apt-get install nmap`
- For RPMs (Fedora, Centos, RedHat & similar):

  - `dnf search nmap`
  - `dnf install nmap`
- (on older versions before `dnf`:)

  - `yum search nmap`
  - `yum install nmap`

#### Scan for DNS

Assuming your router's IP is `192.168.1.1`, you want to perform a service-UDP scan (`-sU`) on port 53 (`-p53`) with Aggressive resolution (`-A`) in order to figure out if it'ss live and working:

```
nmap -sU -p53 -A 192.168.1.1
```

Provided the service comes back **OPEN|UNFILTERED**, then you're golden. If it shows up as **CLOSED** then poke around the configurations a bit more and see if there are options that allow you to reconfigure DNS or simply reboot the router in the hopes it will return to life. If all else fails, call the manufacturer and complain profusely. That sometimes works :)

---

### Configuring the Windows host:

Back to the task at hand: as long as you are sure DNS is running and functioning correctly on the router, you will want to try getting the Windows client working since it's a bit simpler and you have a GUI to count on. I recommend setting up fallback DNS on your router so that it can query multiple DNS servers in the event one fails.

My personal favorites:

- `8.8.8.8` is Google 1
- `8.8.4.4` is Google 2
- `208.67.220.220` is OpenDNS 1
- `208.67.222.222` is OpenDNS 2

Once that is done, your next step should be to see if you can get the Windows system to resolve DNS on the router by manually configuring it in the TCP/IPv4 network settings.

1. Right-click the networking icon in the lower-right portion of the task-bar and head to the `Networking and Sharing Center`.
2. Click your network interface (should be `ethernet 1` or similar) and
   go to `properties`.
3. Click `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)` and hit `properties`
   once more,
4. Click the `User the following DNS server addresses` radial button,
5. Enter the IP of the router/DNS server as the preferred DNS,
6. Enter `8.8.8.8` (google's public DNS) as the alternate DNS, for
   fallback
7. Check `Validate Settings` upon exit
8. Hit `OK` to apply and wait for network interface to
   troubleshoot/restart

You should be able to resolve DNS hostnames at this point on the windows systems. If you are, then you know that for whatever reason, your router's DHCP service is not broadcasting the correct settings, and you may either need to get the manufacturer involved, or you could perhaps tinker yourself in hopes it gets you somewhere. Always refer to the documentation.

If on the other hand, it does not work, I would suspect the cables themselves or the router hardware. There isn't much left to do at this point other than to start replacing the physical devices.

---

### Configuring the Linux Server:

**(You may need to run these commands from the `root`/`sudo` user if you see
   any permission errors.)**

This will likely be a new adventure for you if you don't have much experience with Linux, but no worries.

Start by checking the `/etc/resolv.conf` file with:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

This file is where nameservers, domain names, and search domains are configured. Typically you will see:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

There are two possibilities, depending on what your setup looks like. One is that you have dnsmasq installed, and you get that warning banner telling you not to change your resolv.conf. In this case, it will have the loopback (127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1) just like you see in my configuration, indicating it runs its own DNS service through dnsmasq. If you see this, run the following:

```
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq status
```

If you see `No such file or directory` then dnsmasq is not installed, not a problem. You can either move on without it, or we can quickly install it with
`apt-get install dnsmasq` (or `dnf install dnsmasq`).

If you choose not to install/restart dnsmasq, you could simply edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` file with your favorite text editor (I prefer `nano`) to include the following lines:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4    # That's your router and two fallback DNS servers
```

If you see dnsmasq status is Active/Running, then it is installed and running correctly. If dnsmasq is inactive/dead then you should start it up with the following:

```
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq start
```

dnsmasq typically handles DNS resolution by dynamically changing the `/etc/resolv.conf` file for you. In cases where your resolver is not handling requests properly, or dnsmasq is not properly configured, I highly suggest reading through [its lovely documentation](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html).

But there are really only two settings you need to make sure are in-place for your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
server=/yourlocaldomain/192.168.1.1
local=/yourlocaldomain/
```

These set the server to your local domain name and the IP for the DNS server, and the `local=/yourlocaldomain/` prevents dnsmasq from attempting to resolve to upstream nameservers when your domain is found in the FQDN of the host you are trying to resolve.

For example, if you don't set this setting, and you try to resolve
`emailserver.localdomain`, dnsmasq will ask Google public DNS where `emailserver.localdomain` is...and it will of course respond "I have no clue!"

Setting this will make dnsmasq go:
"`emailserver.**localdomain**` ... I should ask `192.168.1.1` where this is." - and `192.168.1.1`, your router, can respond appropriately with a proper DNS response and the IP of `emailserver.localdomain`.

---

I hope this explanation and long-winded solution helps you out. I tried to account for every scenario I could think of, but let me know if I missed anything or something isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

If the LAN doesn't have too many computers, and/or doesn't depend on internal DNS routes, set the DNS parameters in pv4 configuration to:

```
8.8.8.8
```

and

```
8.8.4.4
```

This will give the DNS resolving work to google's servers.

Comment: this won't resolve hostnames on the local LAN